# How to use itemClickListener in Spinner on Android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

In my application i have one `Spinner` and i should show some data from server into this `Spinner`.
**My server data has :**

```
"sections": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Item 1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Item 2"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Item 3"
        }]
```

For this `spinner` i should set **default text** for show first time and when users **click** on `spinners` **item** show this items instead of default text.

For this i write below codes, but i con't know how can i set `clickListener` to this items for get id of each items!

**My adapter code:**

```
public class DashboardSupportSectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Section> {

    Context context;
    List<Section> model;
    String firstElement;
    boolean isFirstTime;

    public DashboardSupportSectionAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Section> model, String defaultText) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, model);
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
        this.isFirstTime = true;
        setDefaultText(defaultText);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            model.get(0).setName(firstElement);
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
        this.firstElement = model.get(0).getName();
        model.get(0).setName(defaultText);
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_dashboard_support_section, parent, false);
        TextView label = row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
        label.setText(model.get(position).getName());

        return row;
    }

}
```

**My Activity code:**

```
public class DashboardCreateSupportActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.dashboardCreateSupport_sectionSpinner)
    Spinner dashboardCreateSupport_sectionSpinner;
    String defaultTextForSpinner = "Select section";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_create_support);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        dashboardCreateSupport_sectionSpinner.setAdapter(new DashboardSupportSectionAdapter(this, R.layout.row_dashboard_support_section,
                Constants.supportListResponse.getRes().getSections(), defaultTextForSpinner));

    }
}
```

I want when **click** on each item, show id of item in `toast` message.

How can i it?

Comment: Use _spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener_

Comment: @Piyush, can you send to me code with my above codes? please please

Comment: Check [this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.com/p/android-spinner-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dashboardCreateSupport_sectionSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 Constants.supportListResponse.getRes().getSections().get(position).getId();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    dashboardCreateSupport_sectionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Section item  = Constants.supportListResponse.getRes().getSections().getItem(position);
            //use item object
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Use setOnItemSelectedListener.

I would even like to suggest to modify code like:

```
    final DashboardSupportSectionAdapter dashboardSupportSectionAdapter =new DashboardSupportSectionAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        sections, "default");
    dashboardCreateSupport_sectionSpinner.setAdapter(dashboardSupportSectionAdapter);
```

and inside onItemSelected

```
    Section item  = dashboardSupportSectionAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: hey are you here? i have problem with your code? are you here for fix it?

Comment: @Dr.Jake Sure. Please let me know the issue